# How to write jQuery wrapper and plugins to it?

Tags: jquery

I need some object derived from jQuery. It must be same jQuery but different name, `_myQuery` for instance. And I want to write some plugin to `_myQuery` in the same way as for jQuery:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.myPlugin = function () {

    };
})(_myQuery);
```

The goal is that I can use:

```
_myQuery("#id").myPlugin();
```

but following code must give an error:

```
$("#id").myPlugin();
```

This way I can create plugins same name of well known (datetimepicker, for instance), but use it with no conflicts:

```
$("#id1").datetimepicker(); // call bootstrap datetimepicker plugin
_myQuery("#id2").datetimepicker(); // call my custom datetimepicker plugin
```

Comment: `var _myquery = jQuery.noConflict(true);`

Comment: @gustav, do you intend to have both `$` and `_myQuery` in your codebase with the difference that `myPlugin` is only defined for `_myQuery` and not for `$` ?

Comment: @debatanu, yes, exactly.

Comment: @Clive, in this case I can't use jQuery anymore, right? But I need use it through $ or jQuery as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found the right solution. There is a [jQuery.sub](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.sub/) function, but it was deprecated since 1.8:

> Creates a new copy of jQuery whose properties and methods can be modified without affecting the original jQuery object.

One can easily find the source code of jQuery 1.7 and copypast the `sub` function ([here](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.js), for instance).